# Using Chart.SaveImage() in Rider for c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, graphing, rider

I'm trying to learn how to use `System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting` in c# using Jetbrains Rider IDE. I'm creating a simple web page (using razor pages) that just displays a chart. I tried using the following [**tutorial**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-pages/overview/data/7-displaying-data-in-a-chart) to build the chart but it seems outdated and doesn't work in Rider. I found another tutorial to build the chart which is where the code below is from.

The issue I'm having is on line 27 `Chart.SaveImage()`. I'm getting the error message below:

> Module 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c...' should be referenced

I'm not sure how to get this working. Has anyone used Rider and razor pages before that could point me in the right direction?

```cs
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Helpers;

namespace WebAppTestGraphing.Pages
{
    public class index : PageModel
    {
        public void OnGet()
        {
            var Chart = new Chart();
                Chart.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
                Chart.BorderColor = Color.Red;

                var Series1 = new Series("Series 1");
                Series1.ChartArea = "Area 1";
                Series1.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Bar;
                Series1.Points.Add(new DataPoint
                {
                    AxisLabel = "Value1", YValues = new double[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
                });

                Chart.Series.Add(Series1);
                //Chart.Write();
                Chart.SaveImage("/DataChart", ChartImageFormat.Png);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you put your code in the question not like an image?